# Cannot find primary outlet to load angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I have an angular 2 app with authentication, using this html as the main layout

```
<div *ngIf="auth.loggedIn" class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!auth.loggedIn" class="login">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Yet when I login to the app I get the `Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load` error. This error is gone when I reload the page, but keeps happening when I login without refreshing the page after. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There should be one <router-outlet></router-outlet>

Comment: Yes. Your `ngIf` and your containers should be inside it (in component templates).

Comment: Then how would I separate the login form and the dashboard menu if not done this way?

Comment: Your home page component would have two child components containing those two.

Comment: Could you give me a small example of this? I'm not sure how to do this and google doesn't help me a lot either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be one `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` ,

in your code there is no meaning of putting two `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` ,
Logically it does nothing.

You should put all your conditions within , your component html , not into the root html part , as per your code.